# Error opening a Word 2007 (Windows 7) file in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, escaping

With the following line:

```
>>> file = open('C:\Users\mihir\Documents\test.txt')
```

I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Any ideas on why I'm getting that message?

Comment: Maybe, the error is happening while python checks the file header for identifying type.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Python does no such thing.

Comment: @TimPietzcker great to know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backslashes are used to form escape sequences in strings. Always escape them, or use forward slashes in paths.

```
file = open('C:\\Users\\mihir\\Documents\\test.txt')
file = open(r'C:\Users\mihir\Documents\test.txt')
file = open('C:/Users/mihir/Documents/test.txt')
```

Comment: Right, but that would only have led to a "File not found" error because the `\t` would have been interpreted as a tab character.

Comment: @Tim: Except in Python 3, where `\U` is an escape code in `str` literals.

Comment: Oh! You're absolutely right, and I must backpedal a lot. My comments to the question obviously were incorrect, too.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is treated as skipping space so you should use raw string for that. Try:

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\mihir\Documents\test.txt')
```

It should work. Thanks